# <style> Tag ignored by PrinceXML version 15.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, princexml, princely

I am upgrading my heroku server stack for a web app that produces PDFs using PrinceXML with Rails.  In the upgrade, I have updated princexml to version 15.1.  Currently the majority of my styling is included at the top of the body of my .html files using a `<style>` tag. However, any styling that is contained between my `<style>...</style>` tags is simply printed into the pdf as text.

The HTML that my app sends to Prince is

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style type="text/css">
      @page {
      margin: 1.25cm;
      margin-top: 2.5cm;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="pb">
      <div>Some Content below</div>
      <div>...</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The first line of the PDF is `@page { margin: 1.25cm; margin-top: 2.5cm; }` and the style is not actually applied.

Any ideas what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was seeing was a result of the default prince .css files not being in the expected location on my server.  Once I moved those .css files, all of my css began to be interpreted again.  I found the error by looking at the Prince logging on my server at `/app/log/prince.log`